# Send Contacts to Freeshbooks using PHP

Tags: php, freshbooks-api

Is there any way to send contacts(Name,address,Phn etc) to Freshbook using PHP ? I Am using a Form to get details from the user and i need to create a "client" in freshbook using this form field values . Is it possible ?

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. Also some code would make it easier to answer. Please review you question.

Comment: Actually No code implemented yet . I Just asked that is there any way ?

Comment: maybe your answer can be found in the freshbook docs? https://www.freshbooks.com/developers

Comment: Thank you for your comment . Yes,i have gone through that . But couldn't find anything relate to push data to freshbooks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [freshbooks developer site](https://www.freshbooks.com/developers/), there is [a service for creating clients](https://www.freshbooks.com/developers/docs/clients).

Since you were asking specifically about PHP, here's some [sample code reference](https://www.freshbooks.com/developers/sample-code) from the developer site. Some of the references are in PHP, and you'd probably have to adapt one of them to make it do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . But it is actually for pulling data from Freshbooks . I have tried that,but here i need to push data into freshbooks

Comment: Did you read the API? In the link I've sent you, there's a client.create call: "Create a new client and return the corresponding client_id. If a password is not supplied, one will be created at random."

Comment: Plus, a little goggling turned that up: http://www.freshbooks.com/developers/blog/api-updates-clients-contacts

Comment: No, I mean the link I put in my comment.

Comment: Yeah,got it . But how can i implement this ?

Comment: Using the sample code provided by freshbooks is a good start. If you need help with existing code, please post it in your question and we'll be happy to assist. Otherwise, this is the answer to your question..